# JodaTime date formatting issue

Tags: java, datetime, date, time, jodatime

I am formatting my date as follows:

```
String inputDateString = aMessage.getString("updated_at");
                        DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis();

                        DateTime date = fmt.parseDateTime(inputDateString);
                        DateTime now = new DateTime();
                        Period period = new Period(date, now);

                        PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds ago\n")
                            .printZeroNever()
                            .toFormatter();

                        String elapsed = formatter.print(period);

                        dateTextView.setText(elapsed);
```

I would like to be able to show:

```
3 seconds ago if the period is less than 60 seconds
3 minutes ago if the period is less than 60 minutes
3 hours ago is the period is less than X hours
3 days ago if the period is less than X days
```

etc. etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the methods available on [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html), in particular those such as `toStandardSeconds()`.  Using these it should be straightforward to achieve what you're after with a few `if-else` statements making tests such as

```
if (period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds() < 60) {
   // form second-based string
}
else if (period.toStandardMinutes().getMinutes() < 60) {
   // ...
```

I think the `PeriodFormatter` is a red herring in this case, as I don't think it's possible to construct a single formatter that does what you want - and in the `if` blocks you can just get the seconds/hours/etc. directly using the same method calls as in the conditionals.

Comment: Seems like I can't compare it to an int. I get a compile time error
`The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Minutes, int`

Comment: How do you think one might see if an instance of `org.joda.time.Minutes` represents less than 60 minutes?  Have a look at the [API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Minutes.html) and see if you can work it out for yourself (it's not difficult)!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this with a series of `if` statements. If these are your requirements in their entirety, you might even consider doing away with `PeriodFormatter` and extracting the relevant data directly from `Period` (via [`toStandardSeconds()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Period.html#toStandardSeconds%28%29) et al).

You can certainly use `period.toStandardSeconds()` etc to decide on which format to use.